# How to import flex on eclipse

Tags: apache-flex, eclipse, flex-builder-3

I am using the linux Flex builder with eclipse 3.3 on my ubuntu 8.04 machine for the very first time, and I need to modify a preexisting flex project. How do I import this project (its version controlled branch of the flex project) to my eclipse environment.

I have tried creating a new flex project in eclipse and linking the source folder to it, but it does not work.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to install Eclipse plugins for SVN (or whatever SCM you are using) and then check out the project.  If that doesn't work then try to import it (File -> Import -> Existing Projects into Workspace).  If that doesn't work then create a new Flex Project pointed at the base directory for your project.

Answer (score 1):

when all else fails just create a new flex project of the correct type, exit eclipse and copy the project files over to that folder .. restart builder and you'll be up